# What is th purpose of m and q in elliptic curve cryptography protocols?

Tags: elliptic-curves

In crypto protocols that contains calculus on elliptic curves I can often see $\dfrac{m}{q}$$Q$ where $m$ stands for order of EC points group and $q$ is the order of corresponding subgroup of $m$. $Q \in q$.

What is the possible sense of this multiplication speaking mathematically?

It's possible that protocol example will be needed. 
Here it is:[image]

Comment: It is often a requirement to make sure points are from the same subgroup of a prime order. This could be done by multiplying a point by the cofactor.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Ok, in this case, for what purpose  this multiplier(cofactor) at steps of computing $K_a$ and $K_b$ is used?

Comment: Point $u_1$ (a group element) is received by B from A, so it is untrusted, in terms of being from the right subgroup. B is forcing this condition with a cofactor, I guess.

Comment: Related http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18222/difference-between-ecdh-with-cofactor-key-and-ecdh-without-cofactor-key