# Understanding the small cofactor attack with Elliptic Curves of non-prime order

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, brute-force-attack

I came across 2 older answers (2 different but similar questions on the small cofactor attack) which cover this attack.

1. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12614/3941

Here the attacker replaces the $bG$ Bob sends to Alice with $H$ where $H$ is a point of smaller order.

2. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26844/3941

Here the attacker replaces the $bG$ Bob sends to Alice with <s>bG + aH</s> $bG + H$ where $H$ is a point of smaller order. This is unlike Answer 1 where he replaces it with $H$.

Are these 2 attacks the same or are they different attacks?

---

Understanding the attack in **Answer 1:**

Also, after replacing $bG$, this is what the answer says attacker does next to recover Alice's private key $a$

From the answer

> (The attacker is) able to find $a\bmod 8$ by inspecting **following messages**.

By "following messages" does the author mean the messages which Alice & Bob exchange with each other after the DH part of the protocol is finished - i.e in the ideal case without attack, $abG$ would be the symmetric key which Alice & Bob use to exchange messages after DH is done. Is this what the author means by "following messages". i.e. the attacker takes the message encrypted by the derived secret key & then bruteforces it. The reason why I think this bruteforce will be simpler than a full force of the original order is because since $H$ is a point of small order, $aH$ will also be a point of the same small order & hence the attacker would need to try only the smaller number of points of small order to be successful in brute forcing it? Is my understanding correct?

---

Understanding the attack in **Answer 2:**

Here the author says

> As Bob knows the value $abG$ (he does his half of the second phase honestly), he can compute Alice's shared secret with $h$ different alternatives, and so recover $a \bmod h$.

Here the author doesn't explicitly say he uses the messages encrypted by the derived shared secret to find Alice's private key - but I am going to assume that's what is the attack.

Since here the secret key generated by Alice would be $a(bG+H)$ - It's not clear to me whether this would also be a point of smaller order which could be bruteforced like the 1st one. Could someone explain the attack here?

---

Am I on the right track re understanding the cofactor attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding Answer 1**: yes, you understood it correctly. In practice the attacker will have to brute-force the key of the messages sent by Alice.
But it happens often that this bruteforce of the exchanged messages is omitted and implicitly assumed.

**Regarding Answer 2**:
First of all there is a mistake in the question. You wrote

> Bob sends to Alice with $bG+aH$

but in fact $a$ is unknown to Bob, $a$ is the final target of the attack.
Bob just sends $bG+H$, as correctly written in [answer 2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26844/3941).

Now, Bob has computed $bG$, has sent $bG+H$ and has received $aG$ from Alice.

Alice computes the shared secret as $a(bG+H)=abG+aH$ and uses a key derived from it to encrypt her messages.

Bob computes $b(aG)=abG$, now it bruteforce the messages sent from Alice using keys derived from $abG+iH$ for all $i < h$ where $h$ is the cofactor. The one decrypting correctly will give Bob the value of $a \pmod h$.

As you can see the bruteforce effort is the same as in the Answer 1 case.